# Create Logger on Package Level Without Class

Tags: logging, kotlin

I have a kotlin file with a couple of package-level functions and without any class. I would like to add logging to this class but struggle to find an elegant way to give the logger an identifier.

This is an example

```
package com.example.myproject.my_package

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.example.myproject.my_package")

fun bla(term: String) {
   log.info("invoked with $term")
}
```

There are very good best practices to use classes to find a good identifier: [link 1](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-loggers/226) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416869/idiomatic-way-of-logging-in-kotlin). What's the approach if there are no classes?

I would like to avoid writing the identifier by hand and adjust it when the package name changes. Is there a way to get the package name in kotlin?

Comment: Top-level functions are good when they are utility functions. But logic should be located in a `class` (or `object`).

Comment: why that? object oriented programming is only one way to develop your code, there are other paradigm that kotlin perfectly is suited for.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging ?

Comment: That's not because of OOP paradigm. (By the way, Singleton, which `object` stands for, is a procedural pattern.) That's because your functions are gathered in a file, which is not a fully-functional scope — it has no representation in a programming language.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt perfect, works like a charm!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line should do the job:

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(object{}::class.java.`package`.name)
```

The object is doing nothing but nevertheless kotlin will create a class to hold the code. You can then access the class, the package, the package name.

**Note** the usage of backtick because `package` is a reserved keyword. In java it is not a problem because the real method is `getPackage()`. The shorter syntax of kotlin transform this method call by a direct access to the property which name now collides with reserved keywords.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Finally I went with the solution given by Frank's comment. If you are fine with this extra dependency his solution is even more elegant.

Comment: Of course, I was more focused on your precise question "Is there a way to get the package name in kotlin?" than what I would do myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a top-level logger for the generated class like this:

```
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass())
```

Or for the package like this:

```
private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().`package`.name)
```

This has the benefit of not creating an additional class file but it requires atleast Java 7. I have created a library which assists with this and more at https://github.com/kxtra/kxtra-slf4j.

Comment: better answer.  good info, should be set as the accepted.