# Kotlin Unresolved reference: println from gradle on the CLI

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Putting a `println` statement before a kotlin function returns crashes.  stacktrace:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ gradle clean build --stacktrace
w: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: 
e: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/kotlin/src/main/kotlin/example.kt: (14, 5): Unresolved reference: println

> Task :compileKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:359)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:333)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:231)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:203)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:179)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$
```

Taking out the offending line, a successful output:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ gradle clean runShadow
w: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: 

> Task :compileKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :shadowJar
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.

> Task :runShadow
Nov 04, 2017 8:42:47 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: running
Nov 04, 2017 8:42:47 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: integer is                2
Nov 04, 2017 8:42:47 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: integer is                4


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$
```

java:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.kotlin;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    private void run() {
        LOG.info("running");

        int integer = 2;
        LOG.info("integer is\t\t" + integer);
        new demo.Foo();
        demo.ExampleKt.bar();
        integer = demo.ExampleKt.doubleUp(integer);
        LOG.info("integer is\t\t" + integer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App().run();
    }
}
```

kotlin:

```
package demo;

class Foo

val PI = 3.14
var x = 0

fun bar() {
    x += 1
}


fun doubleUp(value: Int): Int {
    return value * 2
}
```

build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    //   id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.1.51"
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    //publishAlways()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'kotlinAdder'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
}
```

environment:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ kotlin -version
Kotlin version 1.1.51 (JRE 1.8.0_151-b12)
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.1.51 (JRE 1.8.0_151-b12)
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_151
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$
```

project:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── net
    │   │       └── bounceme
    │   │           └── dur
    │   │               └── kotlin
    │   │                   └── App.java
    │   └── kotlin
    │       └── example.kt
    └── test
        └── java

12 directories, 8 files
```

It's about as simple as possible, Java invoking Kotlin.  Not sure how else I can simplify it.  This is a [version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712046/262852) problem??

While I'm using netbeans gradle is purely being run from the CLI.  I can even delete out the NB files should that prove useful..

Probably I'm just not printing to the console [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34416869/262852).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

doh.  kotlin [required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36226278/262852).

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ gradle clean shadowJar

> Task :compileKotlin
Using Kotlin incremental compilation

> Task :shadowJar
The SimpleWorkResult type has been deprecated and is 
scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use WorkResults.didWork() instead.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$ gradle runShadow

> Task :runShadow
Nov 04, 2017 10:43:44 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: running
Nov 04, 2017 10:43:44 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: integer is                2
hellooo from kotlin
Nov 04, 2017 10:43:44 PM net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App run
INFO: integer is                4


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
6 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 3 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/kotlin$
```

...

```
plugins {
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '1.8' 
    //   id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.1.51"
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '2.0.1'
}

buildScan {
    licenseAgreementUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    licenseAgree = 'yes'
    //publishAlways()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'kotlinAdder'
    classifier = null
    version = null
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'net.bounceme.dur.kotlin.App'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
}
```

have to add the dependency.